# How to disable warnings and errors in vertical line VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to disable warnings and errors in the vertical line near the vertical scrollbar, in VS Code?

[image: screenshot attached]

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a setting that controls that.  Those are showing up in the `OverviewRuler`.  But you can set them to transparent via this setting in your `settings.json`:

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "editorOverviewRuler.errorForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.warningForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.infoForeground": "#0000"
}
```